# Amazon S3 Bulk File Renaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of files in my Amazon S3 bucket that looks like this (it is more than two, well into the hundreds):

```
09292021-testpilot-state-test-callers-09-29-2021-970669454.csv?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=BRIAN72GRAHWB6KIND7M%2F20210930%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210930T012101Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=8d4de3f18g2c178e1f6c94d0a09bf6a07ffr731454da5ec8940868f499cfc2bc

09272021-testpilot-state-test-callers-09-29-2021-970669454.csv?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=STEVE2313DJFSOODC%2F20210930%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210930T012101Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=8d4de3f18g2c178e1f6c53-309f3f6a07ffr731454da5ec8940868f499cfc2bc
```

I'm trying to do a bulk renaming of them so that you essentially remove everything after the `.csv`, so that the files would then look as such:

```
09292021-testpilot-state-test-callers-09-29-2021-970669454.csv

09272021-testpilot-state-test-callers-09-29-2021-970669454.csv
```

What would be the most effective way to accomplish this?

Comment: How many files? If it is 2, rename them by hand. If it is 2 trillion, write a script. Batch operations might help as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html

Comment: It's more than two, well into the hundreds. What would that look like?

Comment: You can use the Amazon S3 SDK to perform this task. The easiest way is to call the CopyObject and pass in a new name.

Comment: @smac2020 Can you provide an example in the answers of what that would look like?

Comment: Note that you cannot 'rename' S3 objects, at least in the traditional sense of renaming something. You'll need to copy and then delete the original. Be sure to preserve any relevant metadata too.

Comment: Sometimes I do this type of thing by creating a spreadsheet. Put the existing filenames in the first column. Then, write an excel formula to convert it to the desired name. Finally, make a formula like this that turns it into a command: `="aws s3 mv "&A1&" "&B1"`. You can then copy the result into the Command Line and it will rename the files for you. (It actually copies and deletes, but it works like a 'rename'.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Amazon S3 SDK to perform this task. The easiest way is to call the **CopyObject** and pass in a new name. For example, if you were to implement this in Java (you can perform this in other languages supported by the AWS SDK as well), you can use this code:

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.copy_object.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CopyObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.copy_object.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */


public class CopyObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <objectKey> <fromBucket> <toBucket>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    objectKey - the name of the object (for example, book.pdf).\n\n" +
                "    fromBucket - the S3 bucket name that contains the object (for example, bucket1).\n" +
                "    toBucket - the S3 bucket to copy the object to (for example, bucket2).\n";

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
       }

        String objectKey = args[0];
        String fromBucket = args[1];
        String toBucket =  args[2];

        System.out.format("Copying object %s from bucket %s to %s\n",
                objectKey, fromBucket, toBucket);

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        copyBucketObject (s3, fromBucket, objectKey, toBucket);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.copy_object.main]
    public static String copyBucketObject (S3Client s3, String fromBucket, String objectKey, String toBucket) {

        String encodedUrl = null;
        try {
            encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(fromBucket + "/" + objectKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("URL could not be encoded: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        CopyObjectRequest copyReq = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
                .copySource(encodedUrl)
                .destinationBucket(toBucket)
                .destinationKey(objectKey)
                .build();

        try {
            CopyObjectResponse copyRes = s3.copyObject(copyReq);
            return copyRes.copyObjectResult().toString();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.copy_object.main]
}
```

Comment: OP may also need to preserve the object's metadata. Not sure if that happens by default with CopyObjectRequest.

Comment: @smac2020 thank you for this. Where in the script though does it actually eliminate everything after `.csv`?

Comment: You can add that task to you logic. So keep track of the objects and then after you rename them - you can delete the original objects.